# Alternate expresion of L-series coefficients

Tags: elliptic-curves, modular-forms

I was hoping that someone could help clarify a source of confusion for me, I must be doing and saying something wrong but I just don't know what:
Let $E$ be an elliptic curve over $\mathbb{Q}$ and let 
$$L(s,E)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n(E)n^{-s}$$
 be the Hasse-Weil $L$-function of $E$. Finally, let $\tilde{E}$ be the reduction of $E$ mod $p$ and assume that $p$ is a prime for which $E$ has good reduction.

Then
$$a_p(E)=p+1-|\tilde{E}(\mathbb{F}(p))|$$
and setting $a_1(E)=1$ the $p$ power coefficients are given by
$$a_{p^e}(E)=a_p(E)a_{p^{e-1}}(E)-pa_{p^{e-2}}(E).$$

Now looking at Diamond and Shurman, for instance, I find that also we can write
$$a_{p^e}(E)=p^e+1-|\tilde{E}(\mathbb{F}(p^e))|$$
but when I use this expression as a "definition"  of $a_{p^e}(E)$ and do some explicit calculations I don't get the right recursion, for instance I seem to get in practice
$$a_{p^2}(E)=a_p(E)^2 - 2p$$
instead of 
$$a_{p^2}(E)=a_p(E)^2-p.$$

I must be misunderstanding something, but I can't figure out what. Any help?

Comment: I am sorry, I do not understand the "explicit calculations" you did for getting the last two expressions. Could you provide some detail or some reference?

Comment: Sure sorry I should have done that before. I have been using magma, my error could be there as well. Take the curve
$$E: y^2+xy+y=x^3$$
and count its points over $F_7$ and $F_{7^2}$. Then calling magma I seem to get
$$7+1-|E(\mathbb{F}(7))|=-1$$
$$7^2+1-|E(\mathbb{F}(7^2))|=-13$$
and $-13=(-1)^2-2*7$ but the $L$ series coefficient is $-6$. Here are my magma commands:
> E1;
Elliptic Curve defined by y^2 + x*y + y = x^3 over GF(7)
> E2;
Elliptic Curve defined by y^2 + x*y + y = x^3 over GF(7^2)
> 7+1-Order(AbelianGroup(E1));
-1
> 7^2+1-Order(AbelianGroup(E2));
-13
Does that clarify?

Comment: I don't believe that $a_{p^e}(E) = p^{e+1} + 1 - |E(\mathbb{F}(p^e))|$.  Computing with the characteristic polynomial of Frobenius gives that $|E(\mathbb{F}(p^2))| = p^2 + 1 - a_p^2 + 2p$.

Comment: I guess what confuses me then is p.360 of Diamond and Shurman. 

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two different recursions involved here, one for the points of $E$ over ${\mathbb F}\_{p^n}$, and the other for the coefficients of the $L$-function.

If we write $a_p = \alpha + \beta,$ where $\alpha\beta = p$ (so $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are
the two roots of the char. poly. of Frobenius), then

$$1 + p^n - E({\mathbb F}\_{p^n}) = \alpha^n  + \beta^n.$$

On the other hand, the Euler factor at $p$ for the $L$-function of $E$ is
$$(1 - \alpha p^{-s})^{-1}(1-\beta p^{-s})^{-1}$$
$$= (1 + \alpha p^{-s} + \alpha^2 p^{-2s} + \cdots )(1 + \beta p^{-s} + \beta^2 p^{-2s} +
\cdots )$$
$$= 1 + (\alpha + \beta) p^{-s} + (\alpha^2 + \alpha\beta + \beta^2) p^{-2s} +
\cdots ,$$
and so we conclude that $a_{p^n}$ (the coefficient of $p^{-ns}$ in the $L$-function)
equals
$$\alpha^n + \alpha^{n-1} \beta + \cdots + \alpha\beta^{n-1} + \beta^n.$$

These formulas are simply different, as soon as $n > 1.$  The recursion given in
the question describes the second, and not the first.

Comment: Yes, this is right.  Note that in my answer I was working only with an elliptic curve over a finite field.  

Comment: On the other hand, I think I am also right!  On p. 361, Diamond and Shurman define $a_{p^e}(E) = p^e + 1 - |E(F_{p^e})|$, or equivalently as the trace of $p^e$-Frobenius.  Then they write down the recursion that Jude mentions in his question.  So they are indeed mistaken, I believe.

Answer (score 3):

The mistake is acknowledged and corrected in the errata for the third printing:

http://people.reed.edu/~jerry/MF/mferrata3.pdf

Comment: Thanks guys! I had looked for errata but I must have only looked at the errata for the first printing, oops :-\ 

Comment: I am inclined to think that there should be just one file containing all the errata.